# Grid in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grid in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845896/grid-in-windows-phone-7)

I am trying to **divide a grid named "scheduleListBox" into 2 column** and then place the **time** in the variable of **"time"** and the next column to place a button it.

Below is my code:

string selectedFolderName;

```
    string selectedFolderName1;
    string[] timeSplit;
    string timeSaved;
    string timeList;
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        selectedFolderName = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedFolderName", out selectedFolderName))
            selectedFolderName1 = selectedFolderName;


        IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream( selectedFolderName1 + "\\time.Schedule", FileMode.Open, myStore));

        String timeText = readFile.ReadLine();
        timeSplit = timeText.Split(new char[] { '^' });


        foreach (var time in timeSplit)
        {
            timeList = time;
            MessageBox.Show("time " + timeList);




            //Define grid column, size
            Grid schedule = new Grid();
            ColumnDefinition scheduleTitleColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
            //grid1 to hold the label of the alarm
            GridLength titleGrid = new GridLength(320);
            scheduleTitleColumn.Width = titleGrid;
            schedule.ColumnDefinitions.Add(scheduleTitleColumn);

            ColumnDefinition viewBtnColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
            //gl2 to hold the view alarm button
            GridLength viewBtnGrid = new GridLength(80);
            viewBtnColumn.Width = titleGrid;
            schedule.ColumnDefinitions.Add(viewBtnColumn);
            //text block that show the label of the alarm
            TextBlock titleTxtBlock = new TextBlock();
            titleTxtBlock.Text = time;

            //Set the alarm label text block properties - margin, fontsize
            titleTxtBlock.FontSize = 30;
            titleTxtBlock.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 0, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(titleTxtBlock, 0);
            //set the view alarm details button and its properties - margin, width, height, name, background, font size
            HyperlinkButton viewButton = new HyperlinkButton();
            viewButton.Margin = new Thickness(-150, 20, 0, 0);
            viewButton.Width = 100;
            viewButton.Height = 50;
            viewButton.Name = time;
            viewButton.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/AlarmClock;component/Images/page_preview.png", UriKind.Relative)) };
            viewButton.FontSize = 30;
            //viewButton.NavigateUri = new Uri("/viewAlarmClock.xaml?label=" + timeList, UriKind.Relative);
            Grid.SetColumn(viewButton, 1);
            schedule.Children.Add(titleTxtBlock);
            schedule.Children.Add(viewButton);

            //Add the alarm details to alarmListBox
            scheduleListBox.Items.Add(schedule);
        }
    }
}
```

But my above code gave me a error stating that **Exception was unhandled: 0x8000ffff**.

How can i modify my above code?

Comment: Why aren't you using XAML and databindings?

Comment: because i wanted to try out this method. I did databinding before

Comment: So comment out your code line by line to the error disappears. Then you know what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the `Grid` creation code. The exception is outside its scope, most likely. Make sure that:

- Your application is not invoking capabilities not declared in the app
  manifest
- The file in the Isolated Storage exists and is accessible

Is the loop reached in your situation?