# Grid in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have a grid view code below which have **divided into 3 column**.
But i have a problem with the code is that.
When **multiple data** is retrieved.
All the data in the 3 column is overlapping.
**How can i modify the below code such as it will show one after another below it.**

```
           //Define grid column, size

            Grid schedule = new Grid();

            foreach (var time in timeSplit)
            {
                timeList = time;
                //Column 1 to hold the time of the schedule
                ColumnDefinition scheduleTimeColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
                GridLength timeGrid = new GridLength(110);
                scheduleTimeColumn.Width = timeGrid;
                schedule.ColumnDefinitions.Add(scheduleTimeColumn);

                //Text block that show the time of the schedule
                TextBlock timeTxtBlock = new TextBlock();
                timeTxtBlock.Text = time;
                //Set the alarm label text block properties - margin, fontsize
                timeTxtBlock.FontSize = 28;
                timeTxtBlock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);
                //Set the column that will hold the time of the schedule
                Grid.SetColumn(timeTxtBlock, 0);

                schedule.Children.Add(timeTxtBlock);
            }

            foreach (var title in titleSplit)
            {
                titleList = title;

                //Column 2 to hold the title of the schedule
                ColumnDefinition scheduleTitleColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
                GridLength titleGrid = new GridLength(500);
                scheduleTitleColumn.Width = titleGrid;
                schedule.ColumnDefinitions.Add(scheduleTitleColumn);

                //Text block that show the title of the schedule
                TextBlock titleTxtBlock = new TextBlock();

                if (title.Length > 10)
                {
                    string strTitle = title.Substring(0, 10) + "....";
                    titleTxtBlock.Text = strTitle;
                }
                else
                {
                    titleTxtBlock.Text = title;
                }

                //Set the alarm label text block properties - margin, fontsize
                titleTxtBlock.FontSize = 28;
                titleTxtBlock.Margin = new Thickness(60, 20, 0, 0);
                //Set the column that will hold the title of the schedule
                Grid.SetColumn(titleTxtBlock, 1);

                schedule.Children.Add(titleTxtBlock);
                //scheduleListBox.Items.Add(schedule);
            }

            foreach (var category in categorySplit)
            {
                categoryList = category;

                //Column 3 to hold the image category of the schedule
                ColumnDefinition categoryImageColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
                GridLength catImgnGrid = new GridLength(70);
                categoryImageColumn.Width = catImgnGrid;
                schedule.ColumnDefinitions.Add(categoryImageColumn);

                TextBlock categoryTxtBlock = new TextBlock();
                categoryTxtBlock.Text = category;

                //set the category image and its properties - margin, width, height, name, background, font size
                Image categoryImage = new Image();
                categoryImage.Margin = new Thickness(-50, 15, 0, 0);
                categoryImage.Width = 50;
                categoryImage.Height = 50;
                if (category == "Priority")
                {
                    categoryImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/AlarmClock;component/Images/exclamination_mark.png", UriKind.Relative));
                }
                else
                    if (category == "Favourite")
                    {
                        categoryImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/AlarmClock;component/Images/star_full.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    }


                Grid.SetColumn(categoryImage, 2);
                schedule.Children.Add(categoryImage);
            }

            scheduleListBox.Items.Add(schedule);
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way to solve this using my code sample??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickhorn's answer is mostly right.  The issue is you're creating one big grid instead of a row for each item in the list.  Here's a simplified example of your code which uses a model object and databinding instead.

This way you can style everything in the xaml easily and it makes things much simpler.

**Code Behind: `MainPage.xaml.cs`**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<Schedule> _schedules;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] timeSplit = new string[] { "One1", "Two2", "Three3" };
        string[] titleSplit = new string[] { "Title1", "Title2", "Title3" };
        string[] categorySplit = new string[] { "Priority", "Favourite", "Another" };

        _schedules = new ObservableCollection<Schedule>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < timeSplit.Length; i++ )
        {
            _schedules.Add( CreateSchedule( timeSplit[i], titleSplit[i], categorySplit[i] ) );
        }

        scheduleListBox.ItemsSource = _schedules;
    }

    private Schedule CreateSchedule( string time, string title, string category )
    {
        Schedule schedule = new Schedule
        {
            Time = time,
            Title = title,
            Category = category
        };

        if ( category == "Priority" )
        {
            schedule.ImageSource = "/AlarmClock;component/Images/exclamination_mark.png";
        }
        else if ( category == "Favourite" )
        {
            schedule.ImageSource = "/AlarmClock;component/Images/star_full.png";
        }

        return schedule;
    }
}

public class Schedule
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ListBox
    x:Name="scheduleListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Time}"/>
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                    Grid.Column="1"/>
                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Column="2">
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Category}"/>
                    <Image
                        Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I tried your code.
But when i click on the item in the second there will be error.
Only the 1st item is working.

Comment: I had an error in the initial code, in that I was not setting the row on the correct item.  Try out the latest?

Comment: Same problem again. Only the first row of data is providing the right data.. when clicked on second row data it is showing the first row data

Comment: Realized the issue ... updating answer.

Comment: Updated my answer to instead use databinding.  In 99.9% of the cases this is how you should be building your apps instead of building up controls in code.

Comment: @JoeMcBride Your post were very useful. One more thing, i want to  stretch my grid(named as Host) to full screen through only codes(in .xaml.cs) if i clicked the button(Full_Click). Can you help me this!

Answer (score 2):

You should put a `StackPanel` in each column and add the items to the StackPanels instead of the grid.

Answer (score 2):

A stack panel would have your items display one above the other, though, you may lose relationships between the 3 columns. You could also simply set the grid.row to an index.

```
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var title in titleSpan)
    {
        {...} 
        Grid.SetColumn(titleTxtBlock, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(titleTxtBlock, i);

        schedule.Children.Add(titleTxtBlock);
    }
```

Do that for each of your for loops and you'll keep the relationship between the elements. If there isn't a relationship between your elements (ie, the first title isn't related to the first category which isnt' related to the first time) then a stackpanel will likely be the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could add extra columns to the grid when there are more than 3 values.

It could be better to use another control to hold the data to make it more obvious to the user where to scroll to, to see more.

First think of a design, then make it (and ask for help)

Comment: @ben tan, Then add more rows or use a ListBox